# SQL: Counting the Number of Distinct Schools a Student Attended

Tags: sql

I am working with Netezza SQL.

I have the following table (my_table) of student GPA over different years and what school they attended:

```
    student_id year gpa school_year
1           1 2010   6    School A
2           1 2011   4    School B
3           1 2012   4    School A
4           2 2010   5    School A
5           2 2011   1    School B
6           2 2012   2    School B
7           3 2009   5    School A
8           3 2010   6    School A
9           3 2011   5    School A
10          4 2010   5    School A
11          4 2011   7    School B
12          4 2014   6    School C
13          5 2010   4    School C
14          5 2011   2    School A
15          5 2012   2    School A
```

**My question:** I want to find out:

- For any student that attended "School A" in 2010 and had a GPA > 5
- Between the years 2010-2015, how many distinct schools did these students attend?

Here is my attempt to write a query for this problem - I first identified a subset of all rows between 2010 and 2015, then I "tagged" students who attended School A in 2010 and had a GPA > 5. Finally, I used a join to bring all this together - and a two layered count aggregation to get the final answer:

```
with cte_a as
(select * from my_table where school_year >= 2010 and school_year<=2015),

cte_b as
(select distinct student_id from cte_a
where school = 'School A' and gpa>5 and school_year = 2010)

select count_1, count(student_id) from(
select t.student_id, count(distinct school) as count_1
from my_table t
join cte_b
on t.student_id = cte_b.student_id
group by t.student_id)a
group by count_1;
```

I am confused if in the last chunk of code, do I need to use `cte_b` or `my_table`.

Can someone please show me how to do this correctly? In the end, I am expecting the final answer in this format:

```
  count_distinct_schools      count(student_id)
       2                           1
       1                           1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is this 2 queries, or 1?  Are you trying to do query 1 or 2?

Comment: Tag your question with the proper dbms.  sql is a common language use by multiple dbms.

Comment: @ Eric: thank you for your reply! there is only one query here?

Comment: @ jarlh: thank you for your reply! Can you please explain what is "left justified sql"? its a type of indentation?

Comment: Exactly, proper indentation makes SQL much easier. Take a look at the answers you've got and then at your question.

Comment: @stats_noob Does Netezza SQL. support Cross Apply because i want to give you another solution using cross apply?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you need double aggregation, but shouldn't this work?

```
SELECT t.student_id, COUNT(DISTINCT school)
FROM my_table t
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT student_id
    FROM my_table
    WHERE school = 'School A' AND gpa > 5 AND year = 2010
) s ON s.student_id = t.student_id
WHERE t.year BETWEEN 2010 AND 2015
GROUP BY t.student_id
```

Comment: @ eric: thank you so much for your answer! do you think my answer is also correct?

Comment: @stats_noob Your inner `GROUP BY` should give you the result.  What do you need the outer `GROUP BY` for?

Answer (score 2):

At first we find students that attended "School A" in 2010 and had a GPA > 5 using `CTE_Students`.

Then in the main table find all rows with the found student IDs and group them and count the schools.

```
WITH
CTE_Students
AS
(
    SELECT student_id
    FROM my_table
    WHERE
        school = 'School A' 
        and gpa > 5 
        and school_year = 2010
)
SELECT
    my_table.student_id
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT school) AS SchoolCount
FROM
    my_table
WHERE
    my_table.student_id IN (SELECT CTE_Students.student_id FROM CTE_Students)
    AND my_table.year >= 2010
    AND my_table.year <= 2015
GROUP BY
    my_table.student_id
;
```

If you use `IN` instead of `JOIN`, then it is not necessary to get DISTINCT list of student IDs in the first CTE.

Actually, it doesn't matter. Even if you join `my_table` with the `CTE_Students` and `CTE_Students` has several rows with the same student ID, in the end the count of schools is DISTINCT, so all possible duplicates will be eliminated.

So, there is no need to have DISTINCT when finding students that attended "School A" in 2010 and had a GPA > 5, the DISTINCT in the `COUNT()` will take care of it.

Comment: @ Vladimir Baranov: thank you so much for your answer! do you think my answer is also correct?

Comment: @stats_noob, in any case you should prepare a table with a few dozen rows of sample data covering all edge cases and run (test) all variants of the queries and check that they produce correct results. I think your query in the question doesn't produce correct results, because in the final query you join `cte_b` with the whole `my_table` without limiting it to years 2010-2015. Student `1` should have count of schools `1`, but you query would return `3`.

Comment: Ideally, you should provide sample data with expected results (that match the sample data, not fake numbers) in your question. Thus it becomes easy for people trying to answer to check if their query works correctly. Once the query works correctly, you can start thinking about making it [more] efficient (if necessary).

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work.

```
;WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM my_table s
    WHERE s.school = 'school_a'
        AND s.school_year = 2010
        AND s.gpa > 5.0
    )
SELECT s.student_id
    ,count(DISTINCT s.school) AS NumOfDistinctSchools
FROM my_table s
WHERE s.student_id IN (
        SELECT t.student_id
        FROM cte t
        )
    AND s.school_year <= 2015
    AND s.school_year >= 2010
GROUP BY s.student_id
```

Comment: @ psJ01: thank you for your answer!  when you said : select * from students s.... did you mean "my_table s"?

Comment: @stats_noob oh im sorry i named my table as students in my local db.. :)

Comment: fixed it for u :)

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! just in general - what do you think of my original query. is it correct?

Comment: I am working on a new SQL question - do you have any ideas about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76837903/sql-favorite-color-closest-to-some-date thank you so much!