# SQL: Favorite Color Closest to Some Date?

Tags: sql

I am working with Netezza SQL.

I have the following table ("my_table"). In this table, each ID (person) states their favorite color over different periods of time (they can have the same color in different date_provideds, they can also have different colors in the same date_provided):

```
    id favorite_color date_provided
1  111            red    2000-01-01
2  111            red    2002-01-01
3  111           blue    2003-01-01
4  222          green    2005-01-01
5  222         yellow    2006-01-01
6  222         yellow    2010-01-01
7  222         yellow    2010-05-05
8  222           pink    2010-12-31
9  333          black    2008-01-01
10 333          black    2012-01-01
11 333          black    2015-01-01
12 444         orange    2020-01-01
13 555          white    2010-01-01
14 555          white    2010-01-01
15 555          white    2010-01-01
16 666           grey    2009-01-01
17 666           grey    2009-01-05
18 666         purple    2009-01-10
```

**My Question:** For each ID, I want to find out - what was their favorite color(s) closest to the date_provided 2010? (but not looking at date_provideds after 2010)? I.e. Can we infer what someone's favorite color was in 2010?

The final answer would look like this:

```
id favorite_color date_provided valid_color_2010
1  111            red    2000-01-01               no
2  111            red    2002-01-01               no
3  111           blue    2003-01-01              yes
4  222          green    2005-01-01               no
5  222         yellow    2006-01-01               no
6  222         yellow    2010-01-01              yes
7  222         yellow    2010-05-05              yes
8  222           pink    2010-12-31              yes
9  333          black    2008-01-01              yes
10 333          black    2012-01-01               no
11 333          black    2015-01-01               no
12 444         orange    2020-01-01               no
13 555          white    2010-01-01              yes
14 555          white    2010-01-01              yes
15 555          white    2010-01-01              yes
16 666           grey    2009-01-01               no
17 666           grey    2009-01-05               no
18 666         purple    2009-01-10              yes
```

Here is my attempt to do this:

```
   WITH closest_date_provided AS (
        SELECT id, MAX(date_provided) AS date_provided
        FROM my_table
        WHERE date_provided <= 2010
        GROUP BY id
    )
    SELECT my_table.id, my_table.favorite_color, my_table.date_provided,
           CASE WHEN my_table.date_provided = closest_date_provided.date_provided THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS valid_color_2010
    FROM my_table
    LEFT JOIN closest_date_provided
    ON my_table.id = closest_date_provided.id
    ORDER BY my_table.id, my_table.date_provided;
```

Can someone please tell me if I have done this correctly? **Is there an easier way to do this?**

Thanks!

**Notes:**

- Note 1:

I tried to do this for valid_color_2003 at the same time:

```
WITH closest_date_provided_2010 AS (
    SELECT id, MAX(date_provided) AS date_provided
    FROM my_table
    WHERE date_provided <= 2010
    GROUP BY id
),
closest_date_provided_2003 AS (
    SELECT id, MAX(date_provided) AS date_provided
    FROM my_table
    WHERE date_provided <= 2003
    GROUP BY id
)
SELECT my_table.id, my_table.favorite_color, my_table.date_provided,
       CASE WHEN my_table.date_provided = closest_date_provided_2010.date_provided THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS valid_color_2010,
       CASE WHEN my_table.date_provided = closest_date_provided_2003.date_provided THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS valid_color_2003
FROM my_table
LEFT JOIN closest_date_provided_2010
ON my_table.id = closest_date_provided_2010.id
LEFT JOIN closest_date_provided_2003
ON my_table.id = closest_date_provided_2003.id
ORDER BY my_table.id, my_table.date_provided;
```

- Note 2:

Here is the data used to create the original table:

```
 (
    id = c(111, 111,111,222, 222, 222,222, 222, 333,333,333, 444, 555, 555, 555, 666, 666, 666),
    favorite_color = c("red", "red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "pink" ,"black" , "black", "black", "orange", "white", "white", "white", "grey", "grey", "purple"),
    date_provided = c("2000-01-01", "2002-01-01", "2003-01-01", "2005-01-01", "2006-01-01", "2010-01-01", "2010-05-05", "2010-12-31", "2008-01-01","2012-01-01", "2015-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2010-01-01", "2010-01-01", "2010-01-01", "2009-01-01", "2009-01-05", "2009-01-10")

)
```

Comment: “ Can someone please tell me if I have done this correctly?” : does it give the correct answer with your data? If it does then you’ve done it correctly. I’m not sure what other response you’re looking for?

Comment: "Can someone please tell me if I have done this correctly?" No the values `valid_color_2010` for line 6 and 7 are incorrect, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/8V2SbJ8A   (I copied your solution to MySQL, only had to add `year()` in the CTE)